# Chrome Extension files path

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, path

So i want to make a chrome Extension that opens a page if a word is found on the website. But whats the path of a file in the extension? When i use this code on google the site google.com/warnung.html will be opened how to make that the file in the chrome extension will be opened?
**Thank you very Much**

```js
if (document.body.innerText.includes("Blood and Honey")){ 
    window.open("warnung.html")
}
```

Comment: Use chrome.runtime.getURL and declare the file in web_accessible_resources.

Answer (score -2):

(wOxxOm's solution is simpler, so it's probably better)

You can use chrome.windows.create() to open the HTML file.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create

But content scripts don't have access to the chrome.windows API.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#capabilities

That's why the content script needs to send a message to the service worker.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/

The service worker then opens the HTML file in a new window.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Open Extension Page",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Open Extension Page"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*/*"],
            "js": ["/js/content_script.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
function runtimeOnMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.id == chrome.runtime.id && message == "warning") {
        chrome.windows.create({
            focused: true,
            url: chrome.runtime.getURL("/html/warning.html"),
        });
    }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(runtimeOnMessage);
```

/js/content_script.js

```
if (document.body.innerText.includes("chrome")) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("warning");
}
```

/html/warning.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Warning</h1>
</body>

</html>
```